# WP8 : File not Found in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I follow [This](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone) Post to try SQlite implementation in Windows Phone 8 and I am able to do that. Recently I installed Win 8.1 with VS 2013. Now I again tried the same step to run the previously created example is not working now.

I am getting error in below code.

```
#if USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE
        return (Result)Sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2(filename, out db, flags, "");
#else
        return (Result)Sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2(filename, out db, flags, null);
#endif
```

I am getting lite this [image]

Not sure what is wrong with this.

Can any one help me in this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely don't have the SQLite for Windows Phone SDK installed (not the .NET-callable wrapper, the actual engine).  Download it from http://sqlite.org/download.html and then add a reference to it in your project.

Comment: Good to me,too. Thanks

Comment: I already installed SQLite for windows phone 8.1 but still showing the above error. which should i download from the given url?